# Handling async ajax calls within django session

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, asynchronous

I have a Django application, where the template contains for loop in javascript, which iterates all of the check-boxes in some table. For each check box, I send an ajax request to a view function, where I want to save the id of the check box in a list or remove the id from the list (depends on the check state). I need the list to be a part of the request.session dictionary.
The results show me that the ajax calls are asynchronous and that makes my list to be wrongly updated, and inconsistent.
Are there some thread safe data structures which I can store as part of the session, and ensure sync list updating?

JavaScript and Ajax:

```
function checkAll(source, type) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByName(type);
            for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                if (checkboxes[i].checked != source.checked) {
                    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
                    select_row(checkboxes[i], source.checked);
                }
            }
        }

function select_row(row_selector, is_checked) {
            is_box_checked = typeof is_checked !== 'undefined' ? is_checked : row_selector.checked;
            request = {
                url: "{% url 'set_check_box' %}",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                    checked: is_box_checked,
                    check_box_id: row_selector.id,
                    type: row_selector.name
                },
                error: function(response, status, error_msg) {
                    console.log(error_msg);
                }
            };
            $.ajax(request);
        }
```

View function:

```
def set_check_box(request):
    request.session.modified = True
    check_box_list = list(request.session['connects_check_boxes_id_list'])
    check_box_id = request.POST["check_box_id"]
    is_checked = json.loads(request.POST['checked'])
    if is_checked:
        check_box_list.append(check_box_id)
    else:
        check_box_list.remove(check_box_id)
    request.session['connects_check_boxes_id_list'] = list(check_box_list)
return HttpResponse("")
```

Comment: Well, apparently there is async option to ajax requests. I'll post my solution so it might help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I had to do is set async option to false as part of the request parameters.

```
function select_row(row_selector, is_checked) {
            is_box_checked = typeof is_checked !== 'undefined' ? is_checked : row_selector.checked;
            request = {
                url: "{% url 'set_check_box' %}",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                async: false,
                data: {
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                    checked: is_box_checked,
                    check_box_id: row_selector.id,
                    type: row_selector.name
                },
                error: function(response, status, error_msg) {
                    console.log(error_msg);
                }
            };
            $.ajax(request);
        }
```